# How to Automaticallly scroll to a position of a Row inside SingleChildScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, row, singlechildscrollview

I am using a SingleChildScrollView. Its scrollDirection is set to Horizontal with >20 child widgets placed inside a Row Widget. I want to programmatically scroll to a position widget(i.e, 5th or 6th position) in the Row. Is there any way to do it programmatically ?

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Row(
      children: buttons,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: call `Scrollable.ensureVisible` method then

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to doing this is using [Scrollable.ensureVisible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable/ensureVisible.html).

> ensureVisible method
>
> Scrolls the scrollables that enclose the given
> context so as to make the given context visible.

Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _value = 0;
  static final List<GlobalKey> _key = List.generate(20, (index) => GlobalKey());
  final List<Widget> buttons = List.generate(
    20,
    (index) => RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.white,
      child: Text("Button No # ${index + 1}", key: _key[index]),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: buttons,
            ),
          ),
          DropdownButton(
            value: _value,
            items: List.generate(
              20,
              (index) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text("Goto Button # ${index + 1}"), value: index),
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _value = value;
                print("calling");
                Scrollable.ensureVisible(_key[value].currentContext);
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ensureVisible will scroll on both axises if the SingleChildScrollView is a child of another scrollable widget.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent scrolling in both axes (i.e. only allow scrolling in horizontal direction?)

Answer (score 10):

You could define a `ScrollController`:

```
ScrollController _controller = new ScrollController();
```

Pass it to the `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    controller: _scrollController,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Row(
      children: buttons,
    ),
  ),
```

And programmatically scroll it as follows:

```
void scroll(double position) {
 _scrollController.jumpTo(position);
}
```

Or, if a scroll animation is desired:

```
void scrollAnimated(double position) {
 _scrollController.animateTo(position, Duration(seconds: 1), Curves.ease);
}
```

If you'd like to automatically scroll immediately after the layout has been built, you could do so by overriding the `initState` method:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => scroll(500)); // scroll automatically  500px (as an example)
  }
```

Comment: this solution provides a way to scroll by a given amount of width, what i need is to scroll by position. The accepted answer above solves my purpose.

Comment: In case anyone else was wondering, to scroll to the end using the above technique: `_scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.positions.last.maxScrollExtent)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add **ScrollController** in SingleChildScrollView and scroll to your specific position which you want

```
_scrollController.animateTo(
           //here specifing position= 100 mean 100px
                      100,
                      curve: Curves.ease,
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done in a stateless widget, by triggering it in the build method. Used `addPostFrameCallback` to ensure that the scrolling is done after the rendering is done. You'll need to add back state management for the `value` of the choice. But then you have a choice of using GetX, StatefulWidget or any other.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  static final List<GlobalKey> _key = List.generate(20, (index) => GlobalKey());
  final List<Widget> buttons = List.generate(
    20,
    (index) => ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((_)=> index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.lightGreen : Colors.orange)),
      child: Text("Button No # ${index + 1}", key: _key[index]),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final thisWidget = Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title!),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: buttons,
            ),
          ),
          DropdownButton(
            value: 0,
            items: List.generate(
              20,
              (index) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: index,
                  child: Text("Goto Button # ${index + 1}")),
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value != null) {
                WidgetsBinding.instance
                  .addPostFrameCallback((_) => Scrollable.ensureVisible(_key[value].currentContext!));
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
    WidgetsBinding.instance
      .addPostFrameCallback((_) => Scrollable.ensureVisible(_key[15].currentContext!));
    return thisWidget;
  }
}
```