How to have my SingleChildScrollView scrolled to the center in Flutter?
I'm developing a widget using SingleChildScrollView with a horizontal scroll direction (Axis.horizontal). However, I want the initial scroll position to be centered, rather than starting at the beginning. I've searched extensively for a solution but haven't found one yet. How can I achieve this?
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    for (var stepData in widget.documentOverviewEntity.stepData!) {
      if (maxWidth < (105.0 * (stepData.subSteps!.length))) {
        maxWidth = (105.0 * stepData.subSteps!.length);
      }
    }

    return Builder(builder: (context) {
      return Zoom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: maxWidth,
              child: Column(
                children: [
    //some sizedboxes and container widgets
    ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });

As for now, I've tried a solution generated from ChatGPT. What it does is, it first calculates the complete width of the scroll, which is about 5250 according to my print output. However, it doesn't come to the center. It gives a jumping effect from the center to the start as I'm unsure to make it stay at the center.
void _scrollToMiddle() {
    if (_scrollWidth > 0) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollWidth / 2);
      });
      setState(() {
        _isScrollPositionSet = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void _calculateScrollWidth() {
    final renderObject = _scrollKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    if (renderObject is RenderBox) {
      final size = renderObject.size;
      setState(() {
        _scrollWidth = size.width;
      });
      if (!_isScrollPositionSet) {
        _scrollToMiddle();
      }
    }
  }


can you share the singlechildscrollview widget.

@MunsifAli Hi, thank you for replying. I have updated the question with the SIngleChildScrollView code.

why you are wrapping singlechildscrollview inside singlechildscrollview?

@MunsifAli I encounter a render flex overflow both vertically and horizontally. To address this, I use a scroll view for both directions. While the current implementation meets my requirements, I want the horizontal scroll view to start with the scroll being at the center.

I had the same requirement and this helped me. Try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220762/how-to-automaticallly-scroll-to-a-position-of-a-row-inside-singlechildscrollview
